# How to flock turtles within vision distance and heading degrees?

Tags: netlogo, flock

I set a vision parameter in the interface as a slide, suppose vision was set as 5. Now, I want to set turtles flocking behavior within the vision distance, but also taking into account of within less than 90 degrees of turtle's heading.

The behavior is in the  find-flockmates, I copy the codes as below:

```
to find-flockmates  ;; turtle procedure
  set flockmates other turtles in-radius vision   ; flockmates within vision radius distance


end
```

My thought is to add another set, for turtle to rt first, and less than 90 degree, but I am kind of confusing how to sort out flockmates within this degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `in-cone` primitive.  It may do what you want.

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-cone

Note that the cone is centered on the direction the turtle is currently facing, so if you ask the turtle

```
right 45
let flock turtles in-cone vision 90
left 45
```

your will get those turtles in that 90 degree right cone.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your timely help. A quick follow-up, so I think in-cone itself is perfectly align with this scenario, the rt and lt are not necessary. I changed it like this: set flockmates other turtles in-cone vision 90 , whay do you think?

Comment: Certainly that works, but note that without the right/left, the cone will go from 45 degrees left of the turtles current heading to 45 degrees right.  Your question suggested that you wanted a cone only on the right, but if not, there is no need for the turns.